Cors error during sending mail using laravel backend
Access to fetch at
'https://api.domain.com/public/api/v1/auth/verifyEmailForReset' from origin 'https://domian.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Dear friend I am continuously getting the errors mentioned above, I've tried personal Gmail and cpanel-based email IDs to send emails through SMTP.
plese guide me .....i ve broken down

Is this your own backend and frontend? If yes, you have to implement CORS. If not, contact the providre of domain.com and api.domain.com respectively

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
